# How to use in db MySQL decimal?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need insert in the table `tbl_range` of my MySQL database this decimal value:

```
1866752.0
```

And I set field 'range' in the table `tbl_range`:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_range` (
  `Range` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

But in the query insert I've this error:

```
[Err] 1264 - Out of range value for column 'Range' at row 1
```

Comment: What id you set the type to decimal(15,5) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change:

`Range` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,

to

`Range` decimal(15,5) DEFAULT NULL,

because 1st parameter indicates total number of digits including decimal values. So if you are putting (10,5) then you can insert upto 99999.99999. But your required value is greater than that.

Answer (score 0):

`DECIMAL(X,Y)`: X = Number of total digits. Y = Number of digits after the decimal point.

Since you declare it `DECIMAL(10,5)` your maximum number is 99999.99999, a bit smaller than the number you're trying to insert.

Increase the first number a bit, depending on how big numbers you want to be able to handle in your table, or perhaps decrease the second one. Do you really need 5 digits after the decimal point?